# beignet OpenCL xorg connection failed

Tags: c, linux, opencl, intel, xorg

I found this opencl example code:

```
/*
 *  Simple OpenCL demo program
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 2009  Clifford Wolf <clifford@clifford.at>
 *
 *  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 *  Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 *
 *  gcc -o cldemo -std=gnu99 -Wall -I/usr/include/nvidia-current cldemo.c -lOpenCL
 *
 */
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_icd : enable


#include <ocl_icd.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_DATA 100

#define CL_CHECK(_expr)                                                         \
   do {                                                                         \
     cl_int _err = _expr;                                                       \
     if (_err == CL_SUCCESS)                                                    \
       break;                                                                   \
     fprintf(stderr, "OpenCL Error: '%s' returned %d!\n", #_expr, (int)_err);   \
     abort();                                                                   \
   } while (0)

#define CL_CHECK_ERR(_expr)                                                     \
   ({                                                                           \
     cl_int _err = CL_INVALID_VALUE;                                            \
     typeof(_expr) _ret = _expr;                                                \
     if (_err != CL_SUCCESS) {                                                  \
       fprintf(stderr, "OpenCL Error: '%s' returned %d!\n", #_expr, (int)_err); \
       abort();                                                                 \
     }                                                                          \
     _ret;                                                                      \
   })

void pfn_notify(const char *errinfo, const void *private_info, size_t cb, void *user_data)
{
fprintf(stderr, "OpenCL Error (via pfn_notify): %s\n", errinfo);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
cl_platform_id platforms[100];
cl_uint platforms_n = 0;
//CL_CHECK(clIcdGetPlatformIDsKHR(100, platforms, &platforms_n));
CL_CHECK(clGetPlatformIDs(100, platforms, &platforms_n));

printf("=== %d OpenCL platform(s) found: ===\n", platforms_n);
for (int i=0; i<platforms_n; i++)
{
char buffer[10240];
printf("  -- %d --\n", i);
CL_CHECK(clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE, 10240, buffer, NULL));
printf("  PROFILE = %s\n", buffer);
CL_CHECK(clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, 10240, buffer, NULL));
printf("  VERSION = %s\n", buffer);
CL_CHECK(clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, 10240, buffer, NULL));
printf("  NAME = %s\n", buffer);
CL_CHECK(clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, 10240, buffer, NULL));
printf("  VENDOR = %s\n", buffer);
CL_CHECK(clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS, 10240, buffer, NULL));
printf("  EXTENSIONS = %s\n", buffer);
}

if (platforms_n == 0)
return 1;

cl_device_id devices[100];
cl_uint devices_n = 0;
// CL_CHECK(clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 100, devices, &devices_n));
CL_CHECK(clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 100, devices, &devices_n));


printf("=== %d OpenCL device(s) found on platform:\n", platforms_n);
for (int i=0; i<devices_n; i++)
{
char buffer[10240];
cl_uint buf_uint;
cl_ulong buf_ulong;
printf("  -- %d --\n", i);
CL_CHECK(clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(buffer), buffer, NULL));
printf("  DEVICE_NAME = %s\n", buffer);
CL_CHECK(clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_VENDOR, sizeof(buffer), buffer, NULL));
printf("  DEVICE_VENDOR = %s\n", buffer);
CL_CHECK(clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_VERSION, sizeof(buffer), buffer, NULL));
printf("  DEVICE_VERSION = %s\n", buffer);
CL_CHECK(clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DRIVER_VERSION, sizeof(buffer), buffer, NULL));
printf("  DRIVER_VERSION = %s\n", buffer);
CL_CHECK(clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(buf_uint), &buf_uint, NULL));
printf("  DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS = %u\n", (unsigned int)buf_uint);
CL_CHECK(clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY, sizeof(buf_uint), &buf_uint, NULL));
printf("  DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY = %u\n", (unsigned int)buf_uint);
CL_CHECK(clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(buf_ulong), &buf_ulong, NULL));
printf("  DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE = %llu\n", (unsigned long long)buf_ulong);
}

if (devices_n == 0)
return 1;

cl_context context;
context = CL_CHECK_ERR(clCreateContext(NULL, 1, devices, &pfn_notify, NULL, &_err));

const char *program_source[] = {
"__kernel void simple_demo(__global int *src, __global int *dst, int factor)\n",
"{\n",
"int i = get_global_id(0);\n",
"dst[i] = src[i] * factor;\n",
"}\n"
};

cl_program program;
program = CL_CHECK_ERR(clCreateProgramWithSource(context, sizeof(program_source)/sizeof(*program_source), program_source, NULL, &_err));
    if (clBuildProgram(program, 1, devices, "", NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS) {
    char buffer[10240];
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "CL Compilation failed:\n%s", buffer);
    abort();
    }
    CL_CHECK(clUnloadCompiler());

    cl_mem input_buffer;
    input_buffer = CL_CHECK_ERR(clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int)*NUM_DATA, NULL, &_err));

    cl_mem output_buffer;
    output_buffer = CL_CHECK_ERR(clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(int)*NUM_DATA, NULL, &_err));

    int factor = 2;

    cl_kernel kernel;
    kernel = CL_CHECK_ERR(clCreateKernel(program, "simple_demo", &_err));
    CL_CHECK(clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(input_buffer), &input_buffer));
    CL_CHECK(clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(output_buffer), &output_buffer));
    CL_CHECK(clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(factor), &factor));

    cl_command_queue queue;
    queue = CL_CHECK_ERR(clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[0], 0, &_err));

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_DATA; i++) {
    CL_CHECK(clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, input_buffer, CL_TRUE, i*sizeof(int), sizeof(int), &i, 0, NULL, NULL));
    }

    cl_event kernel_completion;
    size_t global_work_size[1] = { NUM_DATA };
    CL_CHECK(clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, &kernel_completion));
    CL_CHECK(clWaitForEvents(1, &kernel_completion));
    CL_CHECK(clReleaseEvent(kernel_completion));

    printf("Result:");
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_DATA; i++) {
    int data;
    CL_CHECK(clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, output_buffer, CL_TRUE, i*sizeof(int), sizeof(int), &data, 0, NULL, NULL));
    printf(" %d", data);
    }
    printf("\n");

    CL_CHECK(clReleaseMemObject(input_buffer));
    CL_CHECK(clReleaseMemObject(output_buffer));

    CL_CHECK(clReleaseKernel(kernel));
    CL_CHECK(clReleaseProgram(program));
    CL_CHECK(clReleaseContext(context));

    return 0;
}
```

It worked with AMD gpu. But when I installed beignet, to try intel integrated gpu I get this result:

```
=== 2 OpenCL platform(s) found: ===
  -- 0 --
  PROFILE = FULL_PROFILE
  VERSION = OpenCL 1.1
  NAME = Experiment Intel Gen OCL Driver
  VENDOR = Intel
  EXTENSIONS = cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing
  -- 1 --
  PROFILE = FULL_PROFILE
  VERSION = OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)
  NAME = AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  VENDOR = Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  EXTENSIONS = cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
Trying to open directly...Device open failed
```

What's wrong?

```
Beignet version: 0.2-2
fglrx version:   2:13.101-0ubuntu3
sys:             amd64_linux26
uname -a:        Linux BetoNIX2 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
lscpu:           
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               2501.000
BogoMIPS:              4988.50
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Comment: Why do you use ICD loader? Is failing to load the device using that method. Can-t you use directly the normal loading?

Comment: To connect multiple gpus

Answer (score 5):

Same problem happened to me. Then I figured that `/dev/dri/card*` access is only for the user root and the video group. You can run your application with `sudo` before the executable file. Good luck!

Side note: I added myself to the video group but it didn't work either. But it's working always fine with `sudo` command before the executable.

Comment: It only works for me only if I log in as `root` on a non-graphical environment. I also tried get it working for a common user by adding him to `video group`, but it didn't work neither. Did you figure out how to get it working for a non-root user?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked that in a while. When I was using it, permissions with root was enough for me. In any case, maybe you can check permissions in a deeper level, such a kernel module permissions (just a thought), because I also remember adding it to the video group and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the last release of beignet and compile it : https://01.org/beignet/downloads it should work for you if you setup properly your Makefile.